# I don't get the desired output from the following code. Point out where I'am going wrong

Tags: java, switch-statement

```js
import java.util.*;
public class lampWatt {
     public  static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        System.out.println("Enter number of bulbs");
        number = x.nextInt();
        int wattage;
        System.out.println("Enter wattage");
        wattage = x.nextInt();
        
      switch(number) {
            case 5 :
            System.out.println("Total price is"+" "+ number*50);
            break;
            case 10 :
            System.out.println("Total price is"+" "+ number*262);
            break;
            case 15 :
            System.out.println("Total price is"+" "+ number*271);
            break;
            case 30 :
            System.out.println("Total price is"+" "+ number*401);
            break;  
            default :
            System.out.println("Invalid Wattage");    
      }
}
}
```

Sample input: 
Enter number of bulbs: 2 
Enter wattage (5/10/15/30): 30 
Sample output:

### Total price is Rs.802

Sample input: 
Enter number of bulbs: 1

### Enter wattage (5/10/15/30): 1000

Sample output: 
Incorrect wattage

Comment: what are you expecting? Hope you mean `Invalid Wattage` and not `Incorrect wattage**` and it's correct output

Comment: Im hoping to get an answer when I input number of bulbs as 2 and wattage as 30. All I'm getting is Invalid Wattage

Comment: your number is not one of 5,10,15,30 so it will go to default.

Comment: In addition to your query , it's good practice to close a scanner when finished with it and to check if (scanner.hasNextInt()) before calling nextInt()

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `switch(number)` should be `switch(wattage)` - because your prices are based on the wattage and your default message of invalid wattage should not apply to the number of bulbs being ordered.

Comment: Thanks Elliott Frisch.
That was stupid of me.
Much appreciated. ^^,